# C++ Using u8 strings as unsigned strings

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, unsigned

C++20 introduced `char8_t` as the type for UTF-8 string and character literals.

`char8_t` is for the most part equivalent to an `unsigned char`, therefore, any arithmetic, logic, or bitwise operations will act as if it were unsigned, emitting unsigned operations instead of signed operations.

Consider a base64 conversion algorithm, most implementations heavily rely on bitwise operations, where signed operations would usually have incorrect semantics.

One could accept a signed character string, or just a `char` string with it's unspecified signedness, and reinterpret the string before operating on it, or one could accept an unsigned string.

If I chose to accept unsigned strings, and make a public API (e.g. a user-facing library function), with the signature of the following:

```cpp
std::u8string base64::encode(std::u8string_view);
```

would this be wrong? As in, would it imply that the function string is intended to operate on UTF-8 encoded strings, instead of 8-bit ASCII or binary buffers?

I presume the response would be "yes."

I could create aliases to `std::basic_string<unsigned char>`, `std::basic_string_view<unsigned char>`, etc, but there would be no way to easily make string literals from them, while one could have easily wrote `u8"Hello, world!"` and passed it into the function.

So it would be harder to use when using string literals.

Is there a better way to accept and use unsigned strings than this?

Comment: Since Base64 is an encoding of binary data I'd probably use `std::span<std::byte>` instead of any kind of `string_view` as the argument type. This makes it clear that this function doesn't care about encoding and operates entirely on the byte-representation of the data being passed in.

Comment: "*C++17 introduced UTF-8 encoded string literals*" - actually, they were introduced in C++11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was unaware, I'll just remove those assertions that I had made entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::u8string base64::encode(std::span<std::byte const> binaryData);
inline std::u8string base64::encode_string(std::u8string_view u8sv) {
  //todo call encode
}
inline std::u8string base64::encode_string(std::string_view sv) {
  //todo call encode
}
```

take a span of const bytes.  Have helper methods that take `u8` and `char` strings.

base64 encoding is for encoding binary data.  You can encode strings in it, and helper methods make that easier.

I made the helper methods have a different name, to make it clear we are encoding a string as a string.  The output of `base64::encode` can be fed back into `base64::encode`, but doing so without it being on purpose is going to be an easy bug to pull off.

Return a `u8string`, as the result is indeed encoded as utf-8 characters.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, as ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, it is technicially true that I am returning a UTF-8 encoded string.

What about accepting the UTF-8 encoded string? Do I break intuition by not reading by characters, but instead by bytes?

Comment: @JadenGarcia You take a UTF-8 string, encode it, and when decoded produce the exact same bytes.  This should sustain intuition.  You want the round-trip to work, anything else is madness.  And, by default, you you prefer UTF-8 strings, because who really wants to work in ASCII?  So make it return UTF-8.  The `string_view` just lets you do something like `base64::encode_string("hello")` and not have it yell at you; feel free to drop it.